# How do I get rid of the percentages in this bar_plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage

I wanted to have a dodge barplot in ggplot2 that show whether a person has savings or not and all this by another variable, region. Since there are missing data I want to include them as another category in the plot and in that way every region would have three bars: one for having, one for not having and one for missing data. Now I made a plot that shows exactly what I want for which I picked up some code on the internet because I really couldn't do it correctly.
The only problem is that now it shows the percentages on the tops of the bars which feature I don't want.
How do I get rid of it? Or how can I round it up at least?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij1WG.png)

```
ggplot(adatok, aes(x=as.factor(region), fill=as.factor(savings)))+
  geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), position="dodge" ) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]),
    y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]  ),
            stat="count", position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: We don't have `adatok` so I can't test this, but presumably deleting the term that runs for 3 lines starting `geom_text` should do it.

Comment: Are you saying you want the number but not the literal `%`, or that you don't want the numbers at all? If the former, stop using `scales::percent`; if the latter, do as user2554330 suggested and don't explicitly add the text with your `geom_text(.)` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use `mtcars` (with its `cyl` and `gear`) to demonstrate two options.

Starting point:

```r
library(ggplot)
data("mtcars")
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), fill=as.factor(gear)))+
  geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), position="dodge" ) +
  geom_text(aes(label=scales::percent(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]),
    y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]  ),
            stat="count", position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image: original plot]

1. If you don't want the literal percent signs, remove `scales::percent` (and see numbers like `0.72727272727272727`) or `round(100*., 1)` it:

   ```r
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), fill=as.factor(gear)))+
     geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), position="dodge" ) +
     geom_text(aes(label=round(100*(..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), 1),
       y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]  ),
               stat="count", position=position_dodge(0.9), vjust=-0.5)+
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
   ```

   [image: no percent sign]
2. If you don't want the numbers *at all*, remove the `geom_text(.)` completely.

   ```r
   ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl), fill=as.factor(gear)))+
     geom_bar(aes( y=..count../tapply(..count.., ..x.. ,sum)[..x..]), position="dodge" ) +
     scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
   ```

   [image: no numbers at all]